# Speeding up a code to filter a matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a symmetric matrix d1 of the from [[row1],[row2] etc] from which I want to remove some elements. The indices of the elements I want to remove are indicated in the list ind (eg ind = [1,2,3] means I want to remove d1[1][1],d1[2][2] and d1[3][3]).

I wrote the following piece of code to write the filtered matrix d1 in d2. However, it is taking forever to run. Is there any way to speed up that code?

```
 for k in range(len(d1)):
     if k not in ind:
         d2.append([])
         for j in range(len(d1)):
             if j not in ind:
                 d2[-1].append(d1[k][j])

 print(d2)
 return d2
```

example:

`d1 = [[1, 2, 3,6,8],[4,5,6,6,6],[7,8,9,6,6],[1, 2, 3,6,6],[1, 2, 3,6,9]]`

`ind = [0,3]`

`d2 = [[5,6,6],[8,9,6],[2, 3,9]]`

Comment: How large is ind, and do you have numpy?

Comment: What should happen with matrix after deletion? Several rows shifted by 1 to the left?

Comment: Try to make `ind` a `set` to speed up lookup. This should be way faster than looping through all ~10000 items each time you check the if condition.

Comment: @rabs ind is around 10,000 and yes I do have numpy

Comment: @mishik I'm not sure I understand correctly. Basically, the matrix represents data and I want to get rid of some of it (by removing the rows and columns because the matrix represents the relationship between all these points)

Comment: In your example `ind=[1,2,3]` means that you want to get rid of full rows 1,2,3 and full columns 1,2,3

Comment: @mishik that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem probably is that if `ind` is a very long list (thousands of entries) than each time you do `if x not in ind` you have to check *the entire list*. Just changing `ind` to be a `set` will probably speed up things a lot. Also, instead of checking the condition in both loops, you could just create a list of good indices to retain. Finally, making it a list comprehension might speed it up still a bit more and make it more readable.

```
ind_set = set(ind)
retain = [i for i in range(len(d1)) if i not in ind_set]
d2 = [[d1[k][j] for j in retain] for k in retain]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to start with simple optimization:

```
good_indices = set(range(len(d1))) - set(ind)

for k in good_indices:
    d2.append([])
    for j in good_indices:
        d2[-1].append(d1[k][j])

print(d2)
return d2
```